# Codeigniter ->group_start() and ->group_end() not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I have this piece of code

```
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('my_table')
                        ->where('monday', '1')
                        ->where('disabled', '0')
                        // ->group_start()
                            ->where('date >=', '2018-09-08')
                            ->or_where('date', NULL)
                        // ->group_end()
                        ->get();
```

If i uncomment group_start() and group_end() it stops working.
The query I want to create should be something like this

```
select * from my_table where monday = '1' and disabled = '0' and (date >= '2018-09-08' OR date IS NULL)
```

I am following this documentation (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) and I don't see anything I am doing wrong...

Comment: I tried the same, but there was no error. I uncommented the lines, but things were good and got the query "`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE monday = '1' AND disabled = '0' AND ( date >= '2018-09-08' OR date IS NULL )`"

Comment: WOW! How can I troubleshoot this? I have `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;` in my database.php file yet I see no errors, I just get an error 500 and php stops execution.

Comment: I just wrote `echo $this->db->last_query();` after completion of `get()`. I mentioned the same name of column in DB. Please cross check your DB, if possible please share the DB image.

Comment: I just figured it out and I am embarrassed to admit it but it might help someone out. I am using codeigniter 2 not 3, so had to use `$this->db->query()` until we update.

Comment: Well! This happens lot of time. Is your problem solved?

Comment: Yes it is. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
## hi, you can try this way

                   $this->db->select('*');
                   $this->db->from('my_table');
                   $this->db->where('monday','1');
                   $this->db->where('disabled','0');
                   $this->db->where('(date >= "2018-09-08" OR date IS NULL)');
                   $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).